# difficulty writing a multilevel for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I have a single dim array with pixels for images stored in it. And I'm trying to print it to a file as a two dimensional array.

Each image is 28*28 pixels, and the array contains 60000 of them.

I have no problem with the math to output a single image:

```
void makeImage(const std::string& filename,const char * insertion, const unsigned int& width, const unsigned int & height)
{
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename.c_str(), "wb"); /* b - binary mode */
    (void)fprintf(fp, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
        {
            static unsigned char color[3];
            color[0] = *(insertion + i);  /* red */
            color[1] = *(insertion + i);  /* green */
            color[2] = *(insertion + i);  /* blue */
            (void)fwrite(color, 1, 3, fp);
            i++;
        }
    }
    (void)fclose(fp);
}
```

So if I where to do:

```
makeimage("myfile.ppm",&myarray[0],28,28); //First image.
makeimage("myfile2.ppm",&myarray[785],28,28); //Second image. ext.
```

But id like to get an image with all 60000 of them in one. as a 6860x6860 pixel image.

But the math to do that is giving me a headache.

Comment: Notice that `6860*6860 = 47,059,600` not equals `28*28*60,000 = 47,040,000` which basically means you can't make fit all of your images exactly because `6,860 / 28 = 245` and `245*245 = 60,025` which is 25 more images.

Comment: And how do you want to arrange the 60,000 images into one big mosaic? Since you are serializing these images column by column, you already have them as one image, 28 pixels high and 1,680,000 pixels wide.

Comment: You need to use another grid, like 100 x 600 images which is: 2800 x 16800 in pixels.

Comment: Btw, C code tagged as C++. Why's that?

Comment: OT: use iostream in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fit these images exactly into a 60000 image square, but you can do, for example, a grid with 600 rows and 100 columns. (The resulting image would be 16800 x 2800.)

I'm sure you could handle the C++ implementation, so here is the math:

You have an array of images:

|----im1----||----im2----|....|----im60000----|

You want to get a composite image:

|----im1----||----im2----|....|----im600----|

|---im601---||---im602---|....|---im1200----|

...

|--im59401--||--im59402--|....|--im60000--|

Here is some pseudocode that will do this.

```
for a in 600
  for b in 28
    for c in 100
      for d in 28
        result[100*28*(28*a + b) + 28*c + d] = arr[28*28*(100*a + c) + 28*b + d]
```

Here, result is your big output image, and arr is your giant input array.

Basically, the first and third loops take care of the position of the images, and the second and fourth loops handle the position of the current pixel in the current image.

It's not very pretty, but it works.
I guess you have to account for the colors, but I assume you're parsing the MNIST data (60000 28x28 images of handwritten digits), which I believe is in grayscale.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: You got the right idea, but using fwrite makes it a bit hard, as i'm writing it on a pixel by pixel basis. or outputting it to another single dim array. that i can bulk copy into a file.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer for you. In general, it's pretty simple to collapse a 2-D array into a 1-D one: you change `arr[a][b]` into `arr[a*b_max + b]`.

Comment: Seems like this is going outside of the bounds of the array. https://wandbox.org/permlink/M30rarWX42HaId2x

Comment: Your code results in a segfault because you're attempting to allocate memory for an array of length 47040000. I don't think you can do this the way you are thinking. Try storing the image in a file, and manipulating that pixel by pixel, instead of trying to load the entire array into the RAM.

Comment: the array on wandbox is just an example, I already have an array containing the data that works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to output 6860 lines of 6860 points and the way you access your file is sequentially, start by determining how a single line is formed:

1. On a single line, there are 6860 points or columns.
2. First 28 points on the first line come from the first image, the next 28 from the second and so on.
3. First 28 points of the 29th line come from the 246th image and so on.

To roughly formulate that in c/c++:

```
int image_index = (y / 28 * 245) + (x / 245);
int source_y = y % 28;
int source_x = x % 28;
int source_index = image_index * 28 * 28 + source_y * 28 + source_x;
```

Comment: 6860 x 6860 is impossible. Images won't fit exactly.

Comment: 6860 x 6860 is absolutely possible, since the images _will_ fit. It's is true that there will be some left-over space in the resulting image, but since the size was mentioned in the question, I suppose the asking party wants to have it that way. The question of how the subimages will be arranged has already been addressed in other comments on the question.

Comment: My point is you can't achieve a square with 60,000 images of size 28x28 pixels.